# How to square root a matrix in R

Tags: r

Suppose that there is a main matrix A.

We want to find a matrix B such that:

```
B %*% B %*% B %*% B = A
```

where `%*%` is the matrix product in R.

The desired outcome is the matrix B.

Comment: You're describing the fourth root, not the square root. To get square root, just do `sqrt(A)`. For fourth root, do `A^(1/4)`. This is simple stuff.

Comment: @Thomas, you're right about the fourth root vs. the square root, and you're right *if* the OP is talking about elementwise (Hadamard) multiplication of matrices, but I think (they could clarify) that they really mean to refer to matrix multiplication, i.e. in R format `B %*% B %*% B %*% B %*% == A` rather than `B * B* B* B == A`, in which case they need a (repeated) matrix square root as described by @Shreyos_Adikari's answer.

Comment: OP: please clarify according to my comment above!

Comment: @BenBolker You are right. user3508921 Can you please clarify a bit.

Comment: Im very sorry, im still learning how to properly write my questions here.
Yes indeed, i meant a fourth square root, but talking of multiplication of matrices, not element by element.
I want a matrix that being multiplied by itself four times (B %*% B %*% B %*% B), gives the matrix i already have (A)

Comment: +1 How in the world did this deserve so many downvotes. It from a fairly new user when posted and was at -3 by now. More a commentary on the voters than the question really.

Answer (score 7):

Have you try to google it out? 
There is a `sqrtm` function present in package `expm`.

**Details**

The matrix square root S of M, `S=sqrtm(M)` is defined as one (the “principal”) S such that SS=S2=M, (in R, `all.equal( S %*% S , M )`).
The method works from the Schur decomposition.

**Examples**

```
# NOT RUN {
library(expm)

m <- diag(2)
sqrtm(m) == m # TRUE

(m <- rbind(cbind(1, diag(1:3)),2))
sm <- sqrtm(m)
sm
zapsmall(sm %*% sm) # Zap entries ~= 2e-16
stopifnot(all.equal(m, sm %*% sm))
# }
```

Please check http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/expm/docs/sqrtm

Another helpful link : http://realizationsinbiostatistics.blogspot.com/2008/08/matrix-square-roots-in-r_18.html

Comment: Please, no link only answers. So your function `sqrtm` is in `expm` and only works for square matrices. Here, the case is unknown. - - Your first link is redirected to somewhere not relevant.